# Is it safe to use a set of functions in registry pattern?

Tags: python, set

I am creating a dictionary of handlers based on an event, but the problem is there is a chance that my register function will trigger multiple times upon run time. I want to ensure that my handlers will be registered only once per event.

I have a dictionary of `event: set(handler)`. I am thinking, instead of a list would it be better if a set was used for this one?

```py
# events.py
from collections import defaultdict
handlers = defaultdict(set)

class Event:
    pass

def register(event: Event, handler):
    handlers[event].add(handler)  # will this ensure uniqueness?
```

```py
# handlers.py
from dataclasses import dataclass
from .events import Event, register


@dataclass
class SomeChanged(Event):
    name: str


def handle_some_changed(event: SomeChanged):
    print(f"{event.name} handled!")


register(SomeChanged, handle_some_changed)
```

Would this ensure uniqueness of the functions stored for the event? How does python handles hashing of functions?
Is there a chance that the same function will generate different hashes for the set? And 2 different functions having the same hash (colliding)?

EDIT: Added more clarification to the question. I haven't encountered it yet, but I read on some post a while back that the `hash` function of python might cause some collisions. So once an application gets big enough I might encounter some hidden issues which might be tricky to debug.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: *"Will this ensure uniqueness?"*: did you have a case where it wasn't? Did you test?

Comment: And `event` is a function? So your question basically is: Can the same function result in different hash codes, maybe when referred to from different places?

Comment: @tobias_k, added more clarification. Event is a class/dataclass. Yes, can they result in 2 different hashes? or 2 different functions hashes collide?

Comment: @trincot not yet, but I am worried it might, and if the application is big enough it will just fail silently and would be a little tricky to track.

Comment: By definition a set allows no duplicate elements. So if you have two functions for which `f == g`, then `set.add(f); set.add(g)` will not increase the size of the set with 2.